# What fields can you update on a balanced payments card through the API?

Tags: php, api, balanced-payments

I'm using the balanced payments v1.1 api and i'm trying to update the cardholder's name, but it's not getting updated and I don't get an error. Is 'name' a field you can't update?

```
$card = \Balanced\Card::get($queryString);
$card->name = $data['new_name'];
$card->save();
```

Comment: i would be *kind of* surprised if any credit card processing facility allowed this

Comment: oh, well 'links' && 'meta' are the only fields in https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/api/cards/#update-a-card so I'm guessing it's just not allowed, thanks by the way

Comment: delete, recreate would be the only option here

Comment: changing "John Q. Cardholder" to "Barak Obama" would certainly not cause any problems, right?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in a comment above, the fields listed on https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/api/cards/#update-a-card, links and meta, are the only attributes that may be updated on a Card. The Card must be tokenized again if any data needs to be "changed".

Feel free to swing by #balanced on Freenode IRC if you have any further questions.